# High memory utilization & thread count due to increasing PoolingClientConnectionManager.setMaxTotal and setDefaultMaxPerRoute

Tags: java, tomcat

Recently for one of our API Services program, we increased the value of

```
poolingConnectionManager.setMaxTotal(MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS)

poolingConnectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(MAX_ROUTE_CONNECTIONS)
```

to 300 from 50.

We did it because our application was chocking while sending requests to downstream components.

Now after doing this change, we are seeing a huge increase in memory utilization and thread count.

> I want to understand what is the probable cause for this?

Server: Linux - 16GB Physical Memory - 2 GB Heap - Java - Apache Tomcat - EDB Postgres Connector

Comment: each db-connection is typically backed by a separate java-thread (used jdbc-driver-type unknown, might be required for more specific solution) => explains the thread-count-increase.
memory-usage might grow massively if driver-features like "prefetch" are used. memory-requirements are typically prefetchSize*RowSize (varchar columns are typically reserved with their max-value from db-meta-data, no dynamic allocation). default-length varchar might cause serious performance degrade. using prepared-statement-cache multiplies this problem.

Comment: @MichaelHauptmann, we are using EDB Postgres Connectors for connecting to Postgres database servers

Comment: my assumptions seem apply to this driver too https://www.enterprisedb.com/edb-docs/d/jdbc-connector/user-guides/jdbc-guide/42.2.8.1/reducing_client-side_resource_requirements.html  but documentation is a bit "undetailed" on the inner workings